# Can I include a local module in my published aar library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I am working on a project with a few modules, something like this:

```
:app
:coreLib
:exportLibrary
:otherLibrary
```

in my `build.gradle` for my `exportLibrary` module I import `coreLib` like this:
`implementation(project("coreLib"))`

and in my app I do the same to include `exportLibrary`:
`implementation(project("exportLibrary"))`

What I want to do is publish `exportLibrary` to a maven repository, and I want it to include everything from `coreLib`.  I haven't found a good way to do this yet.  Adding a transitive flag does not help.  What am I missing?

I hope I do not need to publish `coreLib` too!

I am publishing using `artifactoryPublish`, which includes the artifacts created after running `assembleRelease`.  So, basically how do I make `assembleRelease` produce a binary that includes my local dependency?

Comment: check my answer of question
[Publish Android library with another module as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75248960/6065199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just publish `coreLibrary` in the maven repo.

Then in your `exportLibrary` change the dependency with:

```
implementation "com.xxxx.coreLibrary:x.y.z"
```

and publish it in the maven.
At this point if you check the pom file of `exportLibrary` in the repo you will find the dependency to `com.xxxx.coreLibrary:x.y.z.`

Comment: This is what I ended up needing to do, I don't believe it's possible to do what I was trying to do.

Comment: It's 2023 and this feature still isn't supported :(